# Animating a shape in a JPanel

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics2d

first questing for me here. Been searching forever but cant seem to find the answer.

Im working on a school assignment. Got given an ui and are supposed to make the different panels in it do different things in separate threads. Anyway, Im trying to make a triangle rotate inside one of the JPanels. I have managed to draw it and somewhat rotate it, but when I try to make a loop to update it it just blinks and then disappears again. Heres the code Ive written.

StartAssignment, starts the application

```
public class StartAssignment1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
}
```

Controller, recieves calls from the ui and executes various functions in other classes

```
public class Controller {
private GUIAssignment1 gui = new GUIAssignment1(this);
private RotateShape rotateShape;
private Thread t1;

public Controller() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui.Start();
        }
    });
}

public void startT1(JPanel panel) {
    rotateShape = new RotateShape(panel);
    t1 = new Thread(rotateShape);
    t1.start();
}

public void t1Shutdown() {
    rotateShape.shutdown();
}
```

RotateShape, where Im trying to rotate the damned thing

```
public class RotateShape implements Runnable {
JPanel panel;
private volatile boolean t1Running = true;

public RotateShape(JPanel panel) {
    this.panel = panel;
}

private void draw() {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
    g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(10));
    g2.drawPolygon(new int[] {50,  100,  150}, new int[] {150, 50, 150}, 3);
}

public void shutdown() {
    t1Running = false;
    System.out.println("Shutdown");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (t1Running) {
        try {
            draw();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("loop working");
            panel.repaint();
            panel.revalidate();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain because I don't have access to your GUI code and therefore cannot test it myself, but here's an idea:

It looks like you're rotating your `Graphics2D` object by a fixed amount on every re-render (i.e. every invocation of `draw()`). It's possible that the internal JPanel code initiates the `Graphics2D` at a default rotation before every re-render, which may be why your rotation only causes the shape to "somewhat rotate."

Maybe try storing a variable for the radian offset (e.g. `double offset;`) as a member field of the `RotateShape`class, incrementing it on every re-render, then calling `g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(offset));`?

**Addendum 1:**

The reason that it may draw on top of the previous render is because the `Graphics2D` object is not clearing the canvas between re-renders. One way to fix this is to "clear" the canvas at the beginning of the `draw()` method by filling a rectangle that covers the whole canvas.

**Addendum 2:**

When you call `panel.repaint()`, it triggers the `paintComponent()` method of the `JPanel` object. So, by calling `repaint()` and your own `draw()` method, you are doing two separate renders, which may cause some graphical errors. If you were able to extends the `JPanel` class and use that, you should define an override to replace `draw()`:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // TODO: add your rendering operations here
}
```

This way, calls to `repaint()` should trigger this method.

Comment: The "somewhat rotate" is my bad english, sorry, I got it to turn 10 degrees when I just draw it once. But when I try to draw (and redraw) it from the loop it just flashes then disappears. Will try your idea ofcourse. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @OscarN It's all good, I understood what you meant by that, which is why I came to the conclusion that the rotation is fixed with a reset. Please let me know what happens

Comment: @OscarN The reason that it draws on top of the previous one is because the `Graphics2D` object is not clearing the canvas between re-renders. One way to fix this is to "clear" the canvas at the beginning of the `draw()` method by filling a rectangle that covers the whole canvas

Comment: Actually, it fixed a problem I didnt know I had :-) I got it to work, its spinning around the wrong axel but that I can probably figure out eventually. When I did it my way it just stays in the same place and doesnt update. Done your way it rotates. But, the "real" problem seems to be with `panel.repaint()` when I deleted that line I could see the triangle updating, however, on top of the still visible previous one.

Comment: Ok, I figured something like that, will keep on grinding. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @OscarN Or, an alternative solution to my last one (and possibly a better one) is to realize how `JPanel` works. When you call `repaint()`, it calls the `paintComponent()` method of the object. So, by calling `repaint()` and your own `draw()` method, you are doing two separate renders. Maybe, instead of defining your own `draw()` method, you should declare it as `@Override paintComponent(Graphics g)`, and call `super.paintComponent(g)` at the beginning of the method. This way, calls to `repaint()` should trigger this.

Comment: @OscarN No problem. If you felt like my solution helped you, I'd appreciate it if you upvoted it or selected it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I see, makes sense. However, can I overwrite `paintComponent()` from a separate class? All the examples I've seen do it in a class extending JPanel,

Comment: @OscarN Oh sorry, I just realized that you are given a `JPanel` by the `GuiAssignment1` and cannot change it. In this case then, I would recommend repainting the panel, then calling your own defined draw method. Though in a situation where you can define your own `JPanel` subclass, I would recommend doing that.

Comment: Yeah, thats whats giving me the headache. Thanks alot for making things clearer. However putting the `repaint()` before my own `draw()` still gives me a blank panel. :-/